# Using bootstrap order based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a small and simple project in React Js and using Bootstrap to style it. The problem is that I want the element that is last on the page to be first. For that I want to use order-1 and order-12 from Bootstrap so I need to add them when the page opens on mobile devices. Any ideas on how to do this in a simple way?

Comment: Please, post some code that you struggling with.

Comment: You can use something like `<div class="order-12 order-lg-1">` so that it appears at position 12 on mobile and position 1 on large screens

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to Bootstrap's grid system. So on desktop you want a certain order and on mobile you want a different order?

You can also refer to this documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

Comment: Thanks guys, it's working, I didn't know I could use md in the bootstrap order haha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of Bootstrap classes are responsive, so you can write, for example `className="order-md-1 order-lg-12"` thus at `md` size your element will be first and at `lg` size it will be last.

[Source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes)